# Plotting the implicit function $y=\log_2(1+x\,y)$

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the implicit function $y=\log_2(1+x\,y)$ as a function of $x$.

I tried with `ContourPlot` and `NSolve`, but I'm getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Where is your try?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
f[x_, y_] := y - Log2[1 + x*y];

ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

Comment: Perhaps, `y - Log[1 + x*y, 2]` instead.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I think, it should be `y - Log[2, 1+x*y]`? What you say?

Comment: Indeed, it should.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thx for pointing that out, otherwise, I could have suggested something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach works for me.

```
 ContourPlot[y == Log2[1 + x y], {x, 1, 100}, {y, 1, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete, solve the equation with respect to x, yeilding `x=(2^y-1)/y`and then use the parametric plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{(-1 + 2^y)/y, y}, {y, 0.1, 10}, AspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

[image]

Have fun!